# Comparing limits of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If

$$f_n:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$$

is a sequence of measurable functions and we know that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_X f_n \,d\mu=0,\qquad \qquad \tag{$\star$}$$ then can we conclude that for any measurable set $Y\subset X$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_Y f_n \,d\mu=0$$ because $0\leq\int_Y f_n \,d\mu\leq\int_X f_n \,d\mu$?

Also, does the limit $(\star)$ imply that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=0$ almost everywhere?

Comment: Not even sure why you ask the first question. For the second, you might like $\chi_{[0,1]},\chi_{[0,1/2]},\chi_{[1/2,1]}, \chi_{[0,1/3]},\chi_{[1/3,2/3]},\chi_{[2/3,1]}, \dots $

Comment: thanks @zhw, in my homework, the professor added the pointwise limit as an assumption. But I don't see why the argument I presented fails. So, I asked the second question because wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

The argument you give is correct: if a sequence of non-negative numbers converges to $0$ and another sequence is squeezed between it and $0$, then that other sequence also approaches $0$.  And that other sequence is indeed squeezed between $0$ and the sequence that by hypothesis goes to $0$.

Here is an example of a sequence of non-negative-valued functions $f_n$ on $(0.1,\  1)$ for which

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{(0.1,\  1)} f_n\,d\mu = 0\text{ but } \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\text{ fails to exist at every }x\in(0.1,\  1).
$$
$$
f_{2413}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }\frac{2413}{10000} \le x < \frac{2413+1}{10000}, \\[6pt] 0 & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}
$$
and similarly for all other indices $n$ (e.g. if the index is $46$ then it is the indicator function of the interval $[46/100,\  47/100)$, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes (monotonicity helps). No (but maybe a subsequence does?). Respectively.